# CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable `gender'

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a script that will calculate the BMR of men and women and display results. But I am running into a error that displays 'error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable `gender'.

```
using System;

namespace CSE1101Unit2Lab
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write ("Hello, what is your name?: ");
            string userName = Console.ReadLine ();
            Console.Write (" What is your age?: ") ;
            int age = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
            Console.Write (" What is your weight in pounds?: ");
            int weight = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
            Console.Write (" What is your height in inches?: ");
            int height = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
            Console.Write (" What is your gender? Male or Female? (please type M = male and F = female): ");
            string gender;
            double genderFemale = double.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
            double genderMale = double.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());




            Console.WriteLine (" Your age: " + age);
            Console.WriteLine (" Your weight: " + weight);
            Console.WriteLine (" Your height: " + height);
            Console.WriteLine (" Your gender: " + gender);


            if (gender == "F") 

            {
                genderFemale = 655 + (4.35 * weight) + (4.7 * height) - (4.7 * age);
            }
            else 

            {
                genderMale = 66 + (6.23 * weight) + (12.7 * height) - (6.8 * age);
            }
            int bmr = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
            Console.WriteLine (" Your BMR is: " + bmr);





        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are never assigning `gender`. read what the warning says...

Answer (score 0):

You declare `gender` but don't assign it a default value, and you never set it.

I think you're supposed to change this

```
string gender;
```

to this

```
string gender = Console.ReadLine();
```